# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/mapbox/android/telemetry/MapboxTelemetry;

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, mapbox

I am learning mapbox and I have implemented mapbox with kotlin followed [following mapbox tutorial](https://www.ben.lc/posts/android-mapbox-kotlin-integration/)

but when I run the code I am getting following exception when I run real device

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/mapbox/android/telemetry/MapboxTelemetry;
     at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.module.telemetry.TelemetryImpl.<init>(TelemetryImpl.java:30)
     at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.ModuleProviderImpl.obtainTelemetry(ModuleProviderImpl.java:22)
     at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox.initializeTelemetry(Mapbox.java:167)
     at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox.getInstance(Mapbox.java:64)
     at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:18)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7224)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7213)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2956)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3113)
     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1858)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6820)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:922)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mapbox.android.telemetry.MapboxTelemetry" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapplication-85zEOZQGHEn-PrcXcL50yg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.myapplication-85zEOZQGHEn-PrcXcL50yg==/lib/arm, /system/lib]]
     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:171)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

I want to know what is causing the exception

what I have tried I have added following mapbox proguard-rules

below my proguard-rules.pro

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

-dontwarn com.mapbox.services.android.location.LostLocationEngine
-dontwarn com.mapbox.services.android.location.MockLocationEngine


# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
```

below build.gradle(:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation project(':mapbox-android-sdk-9.5.0')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

I want to know where exactly I have made the mistake, any hints, suggestion, help greatly appriciated!

Comment: implement the library in Gradle

Answer (score 0):

I think when you add mapbox as local dependency, some dependencies not include in project, so add this line of code; that solved my problem, of course produces new error, but remove telemetry error:

```
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:6.2.0'
```